# WebRTC: Connection stuck in 'connecting' state

Tags: android, network-programming, webrtc, video-streaming, webrtc-android

I am trying to implement one-way video stream with WebRTC, from an Android client to a browser.
I have my own working signaling server, and for ICE I connect to 2 Google's STUN servers and a public TURN server by Open Relay Project, which seem to work correctly on their own.

---

When I try to establish peer connection, both sides exchange offers and answers successfully, signaling state in browser only moves to have-remote-offer and then to stable. There seems to be a problem with ICE candidates - every server triggers a **701 error** ("**TURN host lookup received error**."), even though I seem to obtain host and srflx candidates successfully.

Chrome's webrtc-internals page shows that a **candidate pair** has been found and is in **succeeded** state, but it never gets nominated.

[ICE candidate pair stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Bnl.png)

The **peer connection** and DTLS stay stuck in **connecting** state, eventually moving to **failed**. Needless to say, no media track transmission occurs.

---

So far I tried to add code for negotiation needed event, which still only gets me to the same frozen state. I also opened a range of ports for UDP in my Windows 10 firewall settings, but to no avail.

What causes this behaviour and what should I try to successfully establish P2P connection?

Logs and statistics from a sample connection attempt:

https://jsfiddle.net/08cLawvd/

Code I use to initiate the connection and send offer (always from Android device):

```
// connection factory setup
PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions
        .builder(context)
        .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
        .createInitializationOptions();
PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
options.networkIgnoreMask = 16; // ADAPTER_TYPE_LOOPBACK
options.disableNetworkMonitor = true;
factory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
        .setOptions(options)
        .setVideoEncoderFactory(new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), false, false))
        .setVideoDecoderFactory(new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext()))
        .createPeerConnectionFactory();

// video setup
videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(false);
videoTrackFromCamera = factory.createVideoTrack("WebRTC_track_v1", videoSource);

capturer = new CustomVideoCapturer();
SurfaceTextureHelper sth = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThreadOne", rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
capturer.initialize(sth, context, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
videoTrackFromCamera.setEnabled(true);

// peer connection setup and creation
PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration config = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(IceServerService.getIceServers());
config.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED;
config.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE;
config.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE;
config.continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY;
config.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN;
config.iceTransportsType = PeerConnection.IceTransportsType.ALL;
config.keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA;

connection = factory.createPeerConnection(config, new CustomPeerConnectionObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
        sendIceCandidate(iceCandidate); // sends SDP string, sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex to other peer
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
        sendOffer();
    }
});

// sendOffer code
RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit videoConstraint = new RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit(RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverDirection.SEND_ONLY);
connection.addTransceiver(MediaStreamTrack.MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, videoConstraint);
RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit audioConstraint = new RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit(RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverDirection.INACTIVE);
connection.addTransceiver(MediaStreamTrack.MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, audioConstraint);
MediaConstraints constraints = new MediaConstraints();
constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", String.valueOf(false)));
constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", String.valueOf(false)));

connection.createOffer(new CustomSdpObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
        connection.setLocalDescription(new CustomSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
        LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> offer = new LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>();
        offer.put("type", sessionDescription.type.canonicalForm());
        offer.put("sdp", sessionDescription.description);
        Message message = new Message(MessageType.SIGNALLING_ANDROID, new Gson().toJson(offer));
        messageConsumer.accept(message);
    }
}, constraints);
```

Code which accepts the offer and should consume the video track:

```
let peerConnection;

const PC_CONFIG = {
    bundlePolicy: "max-bundle",
    iceServers: [
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302?transport=udp' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302?transport=udp' },
        {
            urls: "turns:openrelay.metered.ca:443",
            username: "…",
            credential: "…",
        },
    ]
};

let onIceCandidate = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
        WebSocketSend("SIGNALLING_BROWSER", JSON.stringify({
            type: 'candidate',
            sdpMid: event.sdpMid,
            sdpMLineIndex: event.sdpMLineIndex,
            candidate: event.candidate
        }));
    }
};

let onAddTrack = (event) => {
    // triggers successfully, but nothing is transmitted
    stream.srcObject = event.streams[0];
};

let setAndSendLocalDescription = (sessionDescription) => {
    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    WebSocketSend("SIGNALLING_BROWSER", JSON.stringify(sessionDescription));
};

let sendAnswer = () => {
    peerConnection.createAnswer().then(
        setAndSendLocalDescription,
        (error) => { console.error('Send answer failed: ', error); }
    );
};

let sendOffer = () => {
    peerConnection.createOffer().then(
        setAndSendLocalDescription,
        (error) => { console.error('Send offer failed: ', error); }
    );
}

let createPeerConnection = (remoteDescription) => {
    try {
        if (peerConnection == null || peerConnection.signalingState === 'closed') {
            peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(PC_CONFIG);
            peerConnection.addTransceiver("video", { direction: "recvonly" });
            peerConnection.addTransceiver("audio", { direction: "inactive" });
            peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = sendOffer;
            peerConnection.ontrack = onAddTrack;
            peerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
        }
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('PeerConnection failed: ', error);
    }
};

let handleSignalingData = (e) => {
    let type = e.type.toUpperCase();
    switch (type) {
        case 'OFFER':
            createPeerConnection(new RTCSessionDescription(e));
            sendAnswer();
            break;
        case 'ANSWER':
        case 'PRANSWER':
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(e));
            break;
        case 'CANDIDATE':
            let candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
                candidate: e.candidate,
                sdpMid: e.sdpMid,
                sdpMLineIndex: parseInt(e.sdpMLineIndex)
            });
            peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            break;
    }
};
```

---

UPDATE

Today I tried the connection with caller and callee on different networks. The **701 error** with ICE candidate gathering still **persist** even on a different network and machine, so in theory, that should lower the probability of incorrect network setup on my end - I think it might be an issue somewhere in the code instead, but I'm not sure.

[Dumps from Chrome's webrtc-internals](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1a7287af9157d5f5bdba95aa721755f420220904171205/726b25)

Comment: androi side: I did not see your stun/turn server. You need adding that in android code.

Comment: Thanks for checking the code, @Jamebes. I get the stun servers from the getIceServers call: 
`PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration config = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(IceServerService.getIceServers());` 
During testing I used the same servers as on browser side.